# string assignment in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to assign string conditionally based on result of certain condition but it is not assigning.

```js
var message = "";
if (true) {
  message += "true";
} else {
  message += "false"
}
console.log(message);
```

Comment: I've changed your code, unedited, to a snippet you can run and see that it is working correctly

Answer (score -1):

1. use ternary operator

   ```
   const message = true ? "a" : "b";
   ```
2. use let

   ```
   let message;
   if(true) {
      message = "true"
   } else { 
      message = "false"
   }
   ```